# How to develop a outlook 2013 add-in that connects to java application

Tags: java, outlook, outlook-addin

we have an existing messaging application that written in java and our emails are generally managed through microsoft outlook 2013, and all the contacts are also managed within outlook contact, double click on the email address will show you his/her contact number.

what i really want to do is the following:

1. I want to develop a outlook 2013 add-in that will do the following, when i hover over the email address, it will give me the option to send his/her message, once i click on that option, it will call up my java messaging application and i could start talking to that person.
2. In this plug-in, because when i double click on the email address, i was able to see his/her number,  i want to be able to click on that number and start calling that person automatically through cisco IP phone.

Anybody has done this before? any suggestion for me to start with?  i am a java developer, but touched c# some years ago.

Answer (score 0):

To directly integrate with the UI that's surfaced with email links in the Outlook message header, you need to develop an IM type of application:

Integrating IM applications with Office
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900715(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0):

"... when I hover over the mail address..." this sounds difficult to realize with an Outlook Add-in.

But you could add a custom task pane or a form region to a mail inspector window that lists all mail addresses found in the mail body or in the address fields. Since you have full control over this view, it will be easier to build such a sophisticated UI interaction. (But maybe it's more intuitive for the user to have ordinary buttons next to the mail address.)

Since your Add-in needs to talk to your Java messaging application, the [Java Library for Microsoft Outlook Add-ins](https://github.com/wolfgangimig/joa) might be an interesting opportunity to develop the Add-in. It is free software and available under the MIT license.